# Pandoc: latex to html ignores custom latex macros

Tags: latex, pandoc

I'm trying to convert a simple latex file (named book.tex), that has custom latex macros, into html.

```
\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter heading}

\chapsummary {
  \item Intro bullet 1
  \item Intro bullet 2
}

Some paragraph of text.

\end{document}
```

Where \chapsummary is just an example of a macro (it might become more elaborate later) that outputs a bullet list.

If I define it at the beginning of this document, then all is well. When I run `pandoc book.tex -o book.html` I get the following html:

```
...
<body>
  <h1 id="chapter-heading">Chapter heading</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><p>Intro bullet 1</p></li>
    <li><p>Intro bullet 2</p></li>
  </ul>
  <p>Some paragraph of text.</p>
</body>
...
```

Ideally, I would like to define it in a separate file (so that it can be easily included in the conversion process, without modifying the original content files). Unfortunately, everything else I tried resulted in the list not being displayed.

I tried creating a metadata.json file:

```
{
  "header-includes": [
    "\\newcommand{\\chapsummary}[1]{ \\begin{itemize} \\#1 \\end{itemize}}",
  ]
}
```

And then running `pandoc --metadata-file=metadata.json -s book.tex -o book.html`. But nothing happens (the same thing happens if I pass in a yaml file). The bullet list is never transformed into HTML.

I've also tried putting the command in a separate latex file (e.g. commands.tex) and then running `pandoc --include-in-header=commands.tex book.tex -o book.html` but that just prints the commands.tex content to the html as regular text, and doesn't do any macro replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the macros into a second `.tex` file, and to pass it as a normal input file to pandoc:

```
pandoc macros.tex book.tex -o book.html
```

This works because pandoc treats multiple input files as if they were a single file, with newlines between each file.